# How to add attribute to python *class* that is _not_ inherited?

Tags: python, decorator

I need to be able to set a flag on a **class** (*not* on an instance of a class) which is not visible to a subclass. The question is, is it possible, and how would I do it if it is?

To illustrate, I want something like this:

```
class Master(SomeOtherClass):
    __flag__ = True

class Child(Master):
    pass
```

... where `hasattr(Master, "__flag__")` should return `True` for `Master` but `False` for `Child`. Is this possible? If so, how? I don't want to have to explicitly set `__flag__` to false in every child.

My initial thought was to define `__metaclass__`, but I don't have the luxury of doing that because `Master` inherits from some other classes and metaclasses I don't control and which are private.

Ultimately I'm wanting to write a decorator so that I can do something like:

```
@hide_this
class Master(SomeOtherClass): pass

@hide_this
class Child(Master): pass

class GrandChild(Child): pass
...
for cls in (Master, Child, GrandChild)
    if cls.__hidden__:
        # Master, Child
    else:
        # GrandChild
```

Comment: You could make it `__hidden`, then only classes where it was directly defined would have a `_ClassName__hidden` attribute.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to write `cls.__dict__.get('__hidden__')`, other than that it's ugly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: nope, that solution didn't occur to me. That will work fantastically. Write up an answer so I can accept it if you want. If you don't, I'll add the answer myself for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close:

```
class Master(SomeOtherClass):
    __flag = True

class Child(Master):
    pass
```

Two leading underscores *without trailing underscores* invokes **name mangling**, so the attribute will be named `_Master__flag`. Therefore if you check:

```
hasattr(cls, '_{}__flag'.format(cls.__name__))
```

it will *only* be `True` for `Master`, not `Child`.

Comment: That's not precisely what I'm looking for -- I don't have an instance of the class, I just have the class. The technique works the same, though.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, it's the same with classes; updated accordingly!